# get the value and status (selected or not) of the option that triggers a multiple select onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, multipleselection

I want to get only the value added/removed from the selection instead of an array with all the selected values.

How can I monitor each individual option instead of the whole selector to see which one has changed?

I know I can compare the previous and current state of the whole selector, but that means saving the previous state, and since it is not just one selector I want to keep track of but an undetermined number of them (one per record on a list of records retrieved from the database), I would very much rather use a simpler way to get the last selected/unselected value if there is one.

Another alternative I just thought of: Instead of keeping track of every selector state, using the onfocus event to save the state of the selector about to be modified (but still, I would prefer a solution where I do not have to compare states, if there is one).

Current solution: use [bootstrap multiselect jquery plugin's onchange option](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options) (bootstrap multiselect turns the selector into a list so each option can be monitored individually using its own onchange event). Any "pluginless" ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists some decent solution. Roll your own jQuery plugin to abstract state comparison.

Maybe this little plugin which triggers custom `optionChange` event on list, providing two additional parameters (value, state) can help you:

```
$.fn.trackOptions = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $select = $(this),
            oldItems = $select.val() || [];
        $select.data("oldItems", oldItems)
        .on("change", function(e){
            var oldItems = $select.data("oldItems"),
                newItems = $select.val() || [];
            for(var i=0; i<oldItems.length; ++i) {
                if(newItems.indexOf(oldItems[i]) == -1){
                    $select.trigger("optionChange", [oldItems[i], false]);
                }
            }
            for(i=0; i<newItems.length; ++i){
                if(oldItems.indexOf(newItems[i]) == -1){
                    $select.trigger("optionChange", [newItems[i], true]);
                }
            }
            $select.data("oldItems", newItems);
        });
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0todjgm4/)

If needed, you can modify it to trigger single event with list of removed options.

Comment: brilliant! It provides the exact functionality I require without adding list nodes to the DOM or loading a much bigger plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Note that [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not available in IE8, so if you are targeting old browsers, I suggest that you include polyfill from that page.

Comment: not the case, but thanks for the heads up. I'll do it anyway :-)